# How to use nested events in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to used nested events. 
When I browse a file, the filename alone being stripped from the full path triggers an event that makes the filename to be transferred to a textbox which has the enable_events set to true, which will trigger another event to call a function and get the pdf details.

If I enable the two commented lines, you can see that the function works and transfers the return value, but I'm trying to separate these two events as the function to get the details of the PDF takes a while.

So the order is:

**__pdfpath__** gets the full path of a certain browsed file which triggers an event that transfers the filename to **__bookfilename__** which should trigger another event which will call a function that will send its response to **__pdfdetails__**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os


def get_pdf_details(pdfname):

    return pdfname + ' was processed'

layout = [

[sg.InputText('',key='_pdfpath_',enable_events=True),sg.FileBrowse(key='_filepath_')],
[sg.Text('',key='_bookfilename_',enable_events=True,size=(40, 1))],
[sg.Text('',key='_pdfdetails_', size=(40, 1) )],


]

window = sg.Window('', layout)

while True:
    event, value = window.Read()

    if event == '_pdfpath_':
        filename = os.path.basename(value['_pdfpath_'])
        window.Element('_bookfilename_').Update(filename)

        #response = get_pdf_details(filename)
        #window.Element('_pdfdetails_').Update(response)
    if event == '_bookfilename_':
        response = get_pdfdetails(value['_bookfilename_'])
        window.Element('_pdfdetails_').Update(response)
```

So the question is, how can I trigger the second event?

I tried creating a second *window.Read()* to create a second loop like this:

```
event2, value2 = window.Read()
```

but didn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps consider using threads. Your problem likely stems from fact that PySimpleGUI doesn't queue up events.  Only 1 event can be outstanding per Read request.  If another comes in, it overwrites the first.
Also, the Text Element's event is a CLICKED ON event, not a changed text event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way through this isn't events traveling around PySimpleGUI. What you need to do is break out your long-running function into a Thread.

EDIT - Since the original answer in early 2019 a lot of continued to be added to PySimpleGUI.

Because having a function take too long be one of the most common problems first encountered writing a GUI, a method was added so that beginners that are not quite ready to write their own threaded code aren't held up.

The `Window.perform_long_operation` takes a function or a lambda expression as a parameter and a key that will be returned when your function returns.

```py
window.perform_long_operation(my_long_operation, '-OPERATION DONE-')
```

You'll get the benefits of multi-threading without needing to do all the work yourself. It's a "stepping stone" approach.  Some users have only been using Python for 2 or 3 weeks when they write their first GUI and simply aren't ready for the threading module.

The Cookbook has a section on this topic and the eCookbook has a number of examples that can be immediately run. http://Cookbook.PySimpleGUI.org and http://Cookbook.PySimpleGUI.org

The Demo Programs are always a great place to look too - http://Demos.PySimpleGUI.org.  There are at least 13 examples shown there as of 2021.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks, that example really helps a lot to  understand what I have to do.

Comment: Awesome. It was your question that prompted finally specifically showed people one way of doing it.  Please let me know if it doesn't work out for some reason. I'll continue to improve that Demo.

Comment: Oh, wow, it's your code...I thought you found it somewhere...wow, thanks for taking the time. Definitely it will help many, there's no any official documentation about how to handle threads with PySimpleGUI.

Comment: @MikefromPSG the code is no longer available at the link

Comment: @Kitwradr thanks for the heads-up. It was removed as there are a lot more examples posted now. This is the safer link: http://demos.PySimpleGUI.org.  There has been a new capability added to make threading even easier for long-running functions that is documented in the Cookbook and in the eCookbook http://ecookbook.PySimpleGUI.org in the section on Multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while True:
    event, value = window.Read()
    process_event(event, value)
def process_event(event, value):
    if event == '_pdfpath_':
        filename = os.path.basename(value['_pdfpath_'])
        window.Element('_bookfilename_').Update(filename)
        value.update(_bookfilename_=filename)
        process_event('_bookfilename_', value)
    if event == '_bookfilename_':
        response = get_pdfdetails(value['_bookfilename_'])
        window.Element('_pdfdetails_').Update(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

PSG has one magic element that can Fire event whenever you want, It's basically is Button, it can be hidden by setting visible=False. Just call `window['ButtonKey'].click()` where you want to fire `'ButtonKey'` event.